# How can I factor this Haskell expression to avoid repeated computation?

Tags: haskell, performance, evaluation

I have this function (produces the fibonacci sequence):

```
unfoldr (\(p1, p2) -> Just (p1+p2, (p1+p2, p1)) ) (0, 1)
```

In here, I notice a repeated expression, `p1+p2`, which I would like to factor so that it is only calculated once. Addition itself isn't an expensive calculation, but for a more general version:

```
unfoldr (\(p1, p2) -> Just (f p1 p2, (f p1 p2, p1)) ) (0, 1)
    where f = arbitrary, possibly time-consuming function
```

In the above situation, `f p1 p2` is calculated twice (unless there's some magic compiler optimisation I don't know about), which could create a performance bottleneck if `f` required a lot of computation. I can't factor `f p1 p2` into a `where` because `p1` and `p2` are not in scope. What is the best way to factor this expression so that `f` is only calculated once?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
unfoldr (\(p1, p2) -> let x = f p1 p2 in Just (x, (x, p1)) ) (0, 1)
    where f = arbitrary, possibly time-consuming function
```

Comment: thankyou! thanks for taking the time on beginner questions like this (:

Answer (score 2):

in `Control.Arrow` there is `(&&&)` which can be used in something like this:

```
unfoldr (\(p1,p2) -> (Just . (id &&& flip (,) p1)) (p1+p2)) (0,1)
```

or even:

```
unfoldr (Just . (fst &&& id) . (uncurry (+) &&& fst)) (0,1)
```

As well in your example `p1+p2` is actually next `p1` so you can rewrite it like

```
tail (unfoldr (\(p1, p2) -> Just (p1, (p1+p2, p1)) ) (0, 1))
```